# How to add default images for custom backgrounds?

Tags: theme-development, add-theme-support

The custom header feature allows (in some code I have found) to suggest several default images to use in the custom header.

Could the same be built in the custom background?

The idea is to have already some textures available for the user to choose from in the theme.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

if you are asking default background image for
`add_theme_support( 'custom-background');` then it can be set using `'default-image'  => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/pattern.png',`

complete code will look like below.

```
$args = array(
'default-color'  => 'f0f0f0',
'default-repeat' => 'fixed',
'default-image'  => get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/pattern.png',
);
add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $args );
```

Comment: Is it possible to implement multiple custom backgrounds with add_theme_support?

Comment: no you can not implement multiple backgrounds. but this might help you http://justintadlock.com/archives/2013/10/13/registering-multiple-default-backgrounds

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest outputting a line of CSS in your header.php file, something like

```
<?='.body {background-image:url(/your/path/to/images/'.$YOUR_CHOSEN_IMAGE.'.png);}'?>
```

Comment: That's not really what I was looking for.

Comment: I could use something that presents 4 or 5 default background images to choose from in the admin area, in the background section of the theme options.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're asking, but here goes.

Assuming that you already know the options [settings api](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API), here's a form you can use to implement that idea:

```
    <label for="bg1">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50" />
      <input class="select_control" id="bg1" name="bg" type="radio" value="bg1" />
    </label>

    <label for="bg2">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50" />
        <input class="select_control" id="test2" name="bg" type="radio" value="bg2" />
    </label>

    <label for="bg3">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50" />
        <input class="select_control" id="bg3" name="bg" type="radio" value="bg3" />
    </label>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/58sWX/

Convert that using the settings API, then use `get_option()` to retrieve your background image url to display it.

If you want to change the CSS, `background: url()`, based on the option value. Then you might need to know [how to use CSS in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201451/how-to-use-css-style-in-php).

```
 <?php
 header("Content-type: text/css");

 <?php if (get_option('your_background_image') != '') : ?>
 body {
      background: url( <?php echo get_option('your_background_image'); ?>;
 }
 <?php endif; ?>
```